# Query works in web browser but gets 400 Bad Request in R?

Tags: r, facebook, api, curl, graph

I have a problem in R with a query to the Facebook Graph API. In the following code I have removed the version, the act and the access_token. If I paste this query in the web browser it works fine.

`https://graph.facebook.com/vX.X/act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/delivery_estimate?access_token= &include_headers=false&method=get&optimization_goal=REACH&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&targeting_spec={"age_min":13,"age_max":24,"genders":[1],"flexible_spec":[{"behaviors":[{"id":"6025000826583","name":"Vivieron en Argentina (anteriormente expatriados - Argentina)"}]}],"geo_locations":{"countries":["BR"],"location_types":["home"]},"facebook_positions":["feed","instant_article","instream_video","marketplace"],"device_platforms":["mobile","desktop"],"publisher_platforms":["facebook","messenger"],"messenger_positions":["messenger_home"]}`

The equivalent query in `R` using the `url()` function is:

`"https://graph.facebook.com/vX.X/act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/delivery_estimate?access_token= &include_headers=false&method=get&optimization_goal=REACH&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&targeting_spec={\"age_min\":13,\"age_max\":24,\"genders\":[1],\"flexible_spec\":[{\"behaviors\":[{\"id\":\"6025000826583\",\"name\":\"Vivieron en Argentina (anteriormente expatriados - Argentina)\"}]}],\"geo_locations\":{\"countries\":[\"BR\"],\"location_types\":[\"home\"]},\"facebook_positions\":[\"feed\",\"instant_article\",\"instream_video\",\"marketplace\"],\"device_platforms\":[\"mobile\",\"desktop\"],\"publisher_platforms\":[\"facebook\",\"messenger\"],\"messenger_positions\":[\"messenger_home\"]}"`

But when my program executes in a Linux the response is:

```
    *   Trying 31.13.83.8...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    * Connected to graph.facebook.com (31.13.83.8) port 443 (#0)
    * ALPN, offering http/1.1
    * successfully set certificate verify locations:
    *   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
      CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
    * SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    * ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
    * Server certificate:
    *  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Menlo Park; O=Facebook, Inc.; CN=*.facebook.com
    *  start date: Nov  6 00:00:00 2019 GMT
    *  expire date: Feb  4 12:00:00 2020 GMT
    *  subjectAltName: host "graph.facebook.com" matched cert's "*.facebook.com"
    *  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
    *  SSL certificate verify ok.
    > GET ...

     HTTP/1.1
    Host: graph.facebook.com
    User-Agent: R (3.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu)
    Accept: */*

    * The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request
    * stopped the pause stream!
    * Closing connection 0
```

I am very puzzled with this problem.

Best regards,
Martín

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JSON` payload instead of encoding request in url like your browser do

## TL;DR

Try something like this:

```
install.packages("httr");
install.packages("jsonlite")
library(jsonlite)
library("httr");
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/vX.X/act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/delivery_estimate";
targeting_spec <- fromJSON({"age_min":13,"age_max":24,"genders":[1],"flexible_spec":[{"behaviors":[{"id":"6025000826583","name":"Vivieron en Argentina (anteriormente expatriados - Argentina)"}]}],"geo_locations":{"countries":["BR"],"location_types":["home"]},"facebook_positions":["feed","instant_article","instream_video","marketplace"],"device_platforms":["mobile","desktop"],"publisher_platforms":["facebook","messenger"],"messenger_positions":["messenger_home"]});
POST(url,body=targeting_spec,encode='json');
```

## Explanation

#### Let's start with working query within browser

You are right, url works from browser.
There is error response `"Unknown path components: /act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/delivery_estimate"` due to lack of `auth_token` but it's not the issue.

#### Let's check it with `curl`

If you try the same url with `curl`, you'll get error message:

`curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 229`

#### Aha moment: you should encode your payload

There is `JSON` in your question:

`targeting_spec={"age_min":13,"age_max":24,"genders":[1],"flexible_spec":[{"behaviors":[{"id":"6025000826583","name":"Vivieron en Argentina (anteriormente expatriados - Argentina)"}]}],"geo_locations":{"countries":["BR"],"location_types":["home"]},"facebook_positions":["feed","instant_article","instream_video","marketplace"],"device_platforms":["mobile","desktop"],"publisher_platforms":["facebook","messenger"],"messenger_positions":["messenger_home"]}`

Well, let's try to get rid of `JSON` part from your url using `curl -d` argument:

```
curl -i 'https://graph.facebook.com/vX.X/act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/delivery_estimate?include_headers=false&method=get&optimization_goal=REACH&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1' \
-d 'targeting_spec={%22age_min%22:13,%22age_max%22:24,%22genders%22:[1],%22flexible_spec%22:[{%22behaviors%22:[{%22id%22:%226025000826583%22,%22name%22:%22Vivieron%20en%20Argentina%20(anteriormente%20expatriados%20-%20Argentina)%22}]}],%22geo_locations%22:{%22countries%22:[%22BR%22],%22location_types%22:[%22home%22]},%22facebook_positions%22:[%22feed%22,%22instant_article%22,%22instream_video%22,%22marketplace%22],%22device_platforms%22:[%22mobile%22,%22desktop%22],%22publisher_platforms%22:[%22facebook%22,%22messenger%22],%22messenger_positions%22:[%22messenger_home%22]}'
```

where `-i` will include the HTTP response headers in the output and `-d` says to `curl` that there is `JSON` payload.

And the `curl` output is:

```
HTTP/2 200
x-app-usage: {"call_count":0,"total_cputime":0,"total_time":0}
www-authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Unknown path components: /act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/delivery_estimate"
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
facebook-api-version: v2.11
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; preload
pragma: no-cache
x-fb-rev: 1001479573
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: no-store
x-fb-trace-id: E736hUurL6h
x-fb-request-id: A6vLWQz7xHTyoFSFKSNrBQb
expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
x-fb-debug: t1UMuN4vVdGU7O1h9NM5xujWahT/6YMANIhxYBqKjkLWQ2D+dDpuIT8QhI2UtzPj9Gp3RpJb7kM9RoaIGgMlxw==
content-length: 166
date: Thu, 28 Nov 2019 21:53:12 GMT
alt-svc: h3-23=":443"; ma=3600

{"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: \/act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\/delivery_estimate","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"A6vLWQz7xHTyoFSFKSNrBQb"}}%
```

It's the same like you'll get from browser without passing auth token that you removed from your question.

#### Final result

To tell R `url()` function that you have `JSON` payload, just use `POST(url, body=b,encode='json');`

Finally, you get the piece of code that should work.